# multiple css3 transitions conflict

Tags: animation, css, conflict

I have a main nav that is a CSS3 only drop down menu with and nice animation as the subnav appears.

I also have on the same page a slider (flexslider) which is also a CSS3 only item.

My problem is that that animations are interfering with each other.  Once I hover over a navigation item, the subnav menu for that item only shows up once the slider is set to slide to the next image, so both animations happen at the same time instead of independent of each other.

Here's a link to the page I'm talking about: http://supermarchepa.com/v3/eng/index.html

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the page seems to be working fine and the slider and submenus animate independently on Chrome and FF.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,maybe it's a safari thing only then. I tested it on Chrome just now and it works fine, Firefox is not as bad as safari but animations are quite choppy. I'm on a mac, not sure of relevance of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Safari doesn't like animating `visibility`, try animating only the properties you need.

```
nav ul#nav ul {
 -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out, margin-top .2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out, margin-top .2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out, margin-top .2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out, margin-top .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out, margin-top .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

This will fix your problem. Though it is a very weird bug indeed.